# asp-all-route-data not calling action method in Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I am running Asp.Net Core 3.1 application where i have one left side menu in layout which i load through partial view.

To set menu link i used the anchor tag like below:

```
var allRouteData = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "menuid", mID.ToString() },
    { "isCalledByMenu", "true" },
    { "where", "tab" }
};
                    
<a class="@clas" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-complete="RedirectToPage('@M.MenuUrl', '@M.MenuName',true)" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#myTab" asp-action="GetSubMenu" asp-controller="Base" asp-all-route-data="@allRouteData">@M.MenuName</a>
```

So when page loads then HTML generate like below:

```
<a class="nav-link btn fuse-ripple-ready" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-complete="RedirectToPage('/OrgOverview/ProfessionalServices', 'Professional Services',true)" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#myTab" href="/Base/GetSubMenu?menuid=9630&amp;isCalledByMenu=true&amp;where=tab">Professional Services</a>
```

Below is action method used :

```
public IActionResult GetSubMenu(int menuid, bool? isCalledByMenu, string where = null)
{
    return ViewComponent("SubMenu", new { menuid = menuid, isCalledByMenu = isCalledByMenu, where = where });
}
```

In Layout page on the top i assigned the tag helper:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

But when i click on the link it is not hitting this action method.
Update: When i click menu then first it hit the list inside javascript where i do some ajax call:

```html
 $('#myTab>li>a.nav-link.btn.fuse-ripple-ready').on("click", function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var requestedPage = $(this).text();
                       
                SetCurrentPageNameSession(requestedPage, false);// ajax call to set some value.
                return true;
                    });
```

In SetCurrentPageNameSession method i do ajax call to set the menu name in server side to some session before calling action method.
like below:

```html
function SetCurrentPageNameSession(CurrentPage, IsBookMark) {

                if (IsBookMark==undefined)
                    IsBookMark = false;
        var url = baseUrl+"Manage/HighlightCurrentMenu/"
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: { CurrentPage: CurrentPage, IsBookMark: IsBookMark },
                url: url,
                dataType: "json",
                async:false,
                success: function (data) {
                var res = data.d;
            },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Then after it anchor tag call the action method.

Please suggest.

Comment: Did u put your action in `BaseController`?

Comment: @MichaelWang, The action method which i shown here is in Base controller only.

Comment: Does it return 404?

Comment: No, It is neither redirect page nor load the page, nothing happens, I verified the console tab also did not found any error or warning anything.

Comment: @MichaelWang, As you suggested to use Route attribute, I just remove the Route attribute from action method and copy the complete url and paste in browser tab, Found like it is hitting the action method but when click on the link not hitting it. Please suggest.

Comment: Hover your mouse pointer over the <a> tag. The target is displayed in the lower left of your browser window. Check the link with the former complete url.

Comment: In the browser dev tools is the request being sent at all in the XHR tab? and if not i would recommend debugging the Ajax unobtrusive library or try to copy the full url as a test to a `data-ajax-url` attribute.

Comment: @MichaelWang, As suggested when i hover on menu then it display the complete url of anchor tag of browser window which is below: localhost:8644/Base/GetSubMenu?menuid=9638?isCalledByMenu=true&where=tab

Comment: @V.Prasad, That's the reason `menuid=9638?isCalledByMenu=true&where=tab`, what's the type and value of `mID`?

Comment: @MichaelWang, in my previous comment i did something wrong menuid=9638& is there not exclamation mark, mid type is int, isCalledByMenu type is bool and where type is string, I put the same screen shot in above also.

Comment: @HMZ, I verified the same in browser Network tab inside developer tools and found like when i click on menu link then i can see some process is running there.

Comment: @V.Prasad So clicking the anchor tag issues a request to the server? check the XHR tab for a request with the same url.

Comment: @V.Prasad, If it just not hitting this action method, what does it return or perform? Please detail more with your usage and we can do nothing with the limited information.

Comment: @MichaelWang, I updated my question here where when click on anchor tag first it hit the particualar event in javascript where i get the value of anchor tag and do some ajax call. then i do return true to hit the server url.Note: same code is working in my MVC project.

Comment: @V.Prasad, `$(this).text()` only return the text contents of anchor tag which is **Professional Services**. I think SetCurrentPageNameSession needs the url, so try 
 `var requestedPage = $(this).attr("href");`

Comment: If still not success, post `SetCurrentPageNameSession` method.

Comment: @MichaelWang, I posted SetCurrentPageNameSession method with comment above.

Comment: @V.Prasad  `<a>`  will never redirect to the link after excute `e.preventDefault();`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could forget `data-ajax`, it also doesn't work on me and I can't find the answer about it. You could code as below and it also can request the `GetSubMenu` and continue to excute next logic.

```
<div id="myTab"></div>

<a class="nav-link btn fuse-ripple-ready"
   href="#">Professional Services</a>


<script>
 $('a.nav-link.btn.fuse-ripple-ready').on("click", function (e) {
     //e.preventDefault();

     $.ajax({
         url: "/Base/GetSubMenu",
         async: true,
         type: "get",
         datatype: "json",
         data: @Json.Serialize(allRouteData),
         success: function (result) {
             $('#myTab').html(result)
         }

     });

     //RedirectToPage('/OrgOverview/ProfessionalServices', 'Professional Services', true);

     var requestedPage = $(this).text();
     SetCurrentPageNameSession(requestedPage, false);// ajax call to set some value.
     return true;
});

</script>
```

---

Comment or Remove `e.preventDefault();`

Calling `preventDefault()` during any stage of event flow cancels the event, meaning that any default action normally taken by the implementation as a result of the event will not occur.

Comment: I added the route but still it is not redirecting to this action method. Are we missing any configuration to set in Startup.cs file?

Comment: If i comment e.preventDefault() then it hits the GetSubMenu action method and posted url will update in browser and the complete application layout is going off, Since this post should be internal and the actual post url is the one javascript method where url is defined after post this url. like: data-ajax-complete="RedirectToPage('/OrgOverview/ProfessionalServices', 'Professional Services',true)". Not sure here why it is not achieving this scenario.

Comment: Hi, @V.Prasad, I updated an alternative solution with your needs. And Finally there is already new issue after dealing with no-response anchor element. It's about anchor element doesn't function well using `jQuery Unobtrusive AJAX` in ASP.NET Core. This issue is off-topic with the original. I suggest you'd better to open a new issue with new topic to target more related experts in.

Comment: I have also provided my answer which is quite similar to your's solution. Now i got the solution.Thank you for your valuable support

Comment: Ok, so there is no need to hits the `GetSubMenu`action?

Comment: Yes right. I used to set the passing value in the specific service where some business logic used. Now when i do ajax call then from there only i pass all these three value to the action method and from the action method i call this specific value to pass all three value to it then in the success of ajax call i redirect the page. Working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for the above asked question:

The issue was when i click on menu link then i used to call first it's anchor click in javascript where i did e.preventDefault() and then used to do some ajax call to pass some value to set in session. Due to e.preventDefault() call after that it was not hitting the action method.

Since i had to pass other three data to server to set somewhere. To do that i set all three value in anchor tag data-link attribute separated with Pipe like below:

```html
data-link="9630|true|tab|/OrgOverview/ProfessionalServices|Professional Services"

 function SetCurrentPageNameSession(CurrentPage, IsBookMark, MenuID, IsCalledByMenu, Where, PageUrl, PageName) {

        var url = baseUrl+"Manage/HighlightCurrentMenu/"
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: { CurrentPage: CurrentPage, IsBookMark: IsBookMark, menuID: MenuID, isCalledByMenu: IsCalledByMenu, where: Where},
                url: url,
                dataType: "json",
                async:false,
                success: function (data) {
                    var res = data.d;
                    if (PageUrl != undefined && PageUrl != '' && PageUrl != null)
                        RedirectToPage(PageUrl, PageName, true, false)
            },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

            }
        });
```

Then in this ajax call success i am redirecting the page with passed page url.

But still i am wondering the same code how it was working in MVC and not in asp.net core.

That's it.